# How to give access to community users to a object?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have one object that has a lookup field to account and a lookup field to a external object and a field type to define if is a record for the account or the external object. With sharing set, I was able to related the account lookup field with the company that the community users belong, but, it only allow one rule, so I was not able to also do the same with the lookup field of the external object.
Even I give access on profile, it doesn't work, what can I do? I only thing about a flow to give access

Comment: ask on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, they may have more ideas and well, looks like it has a chance to be a code-free solution so poor fit for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Uuu, interesting one!

What visibility you'd want, the ones linked to external objects should be visible to all community users? Everybody in the org? You might still be able to pull it off with sharing rule (yes, community's supposed to use sharing sets but don't let that stop you)

[image]

Do you get anything interesting when running this query? (it's supposed to find all hidden community roles that normally don't show up in the tree)

```
select id, name, ParentRoleId, PortalRole
from userrole
where PortalRole != null
```

If it has to be specific records for specific users you'll run out of sharing rules so that's not the way to go... Apex managed sharing? Some nightly job that runs through all records and adds/removes `YourObject__Share` records?

Some custom component that'd be running the query?

Is there something else you can base the sharing set on, like "User with somefield = A, share all YourObjects with somefield = A" and then it's your job (trigger? again nightly job?) to make sure it's set nicely on all eligible records?